# what is the use of data-priority parameter in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it only used for show the column as hide ? Is it not prioritized the column ?

```
<thead id="th">
    <tr id="tr1">
        <th data-priority="1" >sachin</th>
        <th data-priority="2" >dravid</th>
        <th data-priority="3" >ganguly</th>
    </tr>            
</thead>
```

see the above example. based on the priority .it display as sachin,dravid,ganguly as a fist,second,third column. it is fine. see the below example.

```
<thead id="th">
    <tr id="tr1">
        <th data-priority="3" >sachin</th>
        <th data-priority="1" >dravid</th>
        <th data-priority="2" >ganguly</th>
    </tr>            
</thead>
```

see the another example. based on the priority it should display dravid as a fist column, ganguly as a second column and sachin as a third column. but jquery mobile is working as well. then what is the use of data-priority here.

Comment: Header with smaller number has priority to be shown on smaller screens. On your second example, resize the window to hide any items except for _dravid_.

Comment: You need to set the data-mode at the table tag in order for this to work. Check out the example in the API docs: https://api.jquerymobile.com/table-reflow/